# qDebug() stopped to work after Qt upgrade

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, qdebug

I just upgraded my Qt from 5.2 to 5.3. In Qt Creator I have now no application output at all: qDebug() and cout are not working. In "Build & Run"/"Qt Versions" it was set to 5.2 and I found that this problem may be related to bad library in use... so I've changed it to 5.3 (which I now have) but still nothing: program builds and works but doesn't let me use qDebug(). I'm using Arch Linux.

Comment: Try adding `QT += console` to the .pro file and rebuilding the project.

Comment: @MicroPenguin it's "CONFIG += console" but anyway: my application is not console application but widget application and output information is needed by my only to debug and it was always appearing at "Aplication Output" frame.

Comment: I created another frame, named it DebugFrame and I push all the needed information there... still, problem is not really solved, it's overdoing things.

Comment: Good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295325/where-is-located-the-qdebug-qwarning-qcritical-and-qfatal-log-by-default-on-qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be [Arch Linux bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/40583) so really not a problem that could be answered here.