# Where is located the qDebug qWarning qCritical and qFatal log by default on Qt?

Tags: qt, qt5, qdebug

When running my Qt5 application on linux, I don't see any output from qDebug, qWarning, qCritical or qFatal. I know that I can use `qInstallMsgHandler` to install a message handler and see them, but this is rather heavyweight.

I just want to check the qWarning log to see if there is any signal that mis-connected. Is there a way to look at this log? A special command-line option, an environment variable?

I think I remember that in the past, everything was printed to stderr, perhaps that's a Qt5 change?

Answer (score 17):

**Please do not make the mistake of assuming that qDebug, qWarning, qCritical and qFatal always log on standard error.** That's absolutely not the case.

The actual destination varies depending on the Qt configuration and the targeting OS. Plus, 5.4 and then 5.11 introduced some behavioural changes. See [here](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2014-July/017588.html) and [here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/89357/) for discussions.

TL;DR:

**On Qt >= 5.11**

- If the process' stderr has a console attached, that's where the debug log will go.
- If you want to *always* log on stderr, set `QT_FORCE_STDERR_LOGGING` to `1`.
- In alternative, set `QT_ASSUME_STDERR_HAS_CONSOLE` to `1`. I suspect this one is meant to be used by a parent process that reads a child's stderr and shows it to the user somehow.
- `QT_LOGGING_TO_CONSOLE` to `1` still works, but Qt will complain.

**On Qt >= 5.4 and < 5.11**

- If you want to always log on stderr, set the `QT_LOGGING_TO_CONSOLE` environment variable to `1`.
- If you do not want to log on stderr, the `QT_LOGGING_TO_CONSOLE` environment variable to `0` (this will force logging through the native system logger).
- If the `QT_LOGGING_TO_CONSOLE` environment variable *is not set*, then whether logging to the console or not depends on whether the application is running in a TTY (on UNIX) or whether there's a console window (on Windows).

**On Qt < 5.4**, the situation is more confusing.

- If Qt has been built with support for a specific logging framework (e.g. SLOG2, journald, Android log, etc.) then logging always goes to that framework
- Otherwise on UNIX it goes to stderr
- Otherwise on Windows OutputDebugString or stderr is used depending whether the app is a console app.

The problem with the pre-5.4 approach was that, f.i., under Unix IDEs would not capture an application's debug output if Qt had been built with journald support. That's because the output went to journald, not to the IDE. In 5.4 the approach has been made more flexible and uniform across OSes.

Comment: This is as you says except that QT_LOGGING_TO_CONSOLE seem to work with Qt 5.3.2 (as packaged by ArchLinux)

Comment: Maybe Arch backported the patches? See the discussion in this bug report https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/40583

Comment: I only found this after finding the answer elsewhere on Arch linux forums, but the answer is perfect.  My question was more "why did qDebug() stop going to console after upgrade Qt (past 5.3)?"  This thread should be referenced from a bunch of other stackoverflow questions.

Answer (score 5):

If you happen to run Arch Linux, which compiles Qt with the `-journald` option, all debug output is per default directed to the systemd journal (display with `journalctl`).

You can override this behaviour by defining `QT_LOGGING_TO_CONSOLE=1` as an environment variable.

Comment: QT_LOGGING_TO_CONSOLE is currently deprecated as @peppe already said in his answer (QtCreator >5.15). Using the QT_ASSUME_STDERR_HAS_CONSOLE=1 environment variable and starting QtCreator from terminal, makes the output to be printed on Arch. See: bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=259035 for further info about the issue

Answer (score 1):

They are still printed to standard error.

If you launch the application from the command line, it is usually printed there, or if using Qt Creator, it's displayed in the Application Output window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio, qDebug etc are printed to the output window in the IDE.